# Translate this problem to graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, order-theory

Say I have a size $k$ set called $S_k$ with elements that are natural numbers (repetitions are allowed). For instance $\{2, 8, 6, 6, 1, 3\}$ is a valid set for $k = 6.$ I am trying to find the least number of strict partial orders such that each partial order uses a unique element. For instance, in the above set I have a minimum of two strict partial orders: $8>6>3>2>1$ and $6$.

Comment: If repetitions are allowed then that's usually called a mutiset (or bag), not a set.

Answer (score 1):

Create a digraph $G=(V,A)$ as follows:

- $V=S_k$: so one node per element of the multi set $S_k$
- Create an arc from $u$ to $v$ if and only if $u<v$

You are now looking for a minimum number of paths that cover your graph $G$. Since $G$ has a transitive structure, you can use the [Dilworth Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) to answer your question (in polynomial time). It will give you an algorithm based on maximum flows that gives you exactly what you want.